# Sound effects for websites

Tags: sound

Is there a standard go-to place for sound effects for websites? Preferably ones that are free to use for whatever I'd like. Kinda like a bootstrap for sounds instead of css and javascript.

Answer (score 3):

Don't.

Really.  Nothing turns people away from websites like unexpected sounds.

Comment: It's a site that involves exchanging messages. Just looking for a nice subtle clip to play when a message is received. Don't assume the worst.